# What is wrong with my question about retrieving a Word document's creation time?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

I posted a question today, which gained five downvotes in 20 minutes.

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466873/how-to-get-the-real-creation-date-of-a-file-from-the-meta-data

So it looks like my question is a full garbage - in the comments I read, that creation date of a file can't be stored in a system.

Well, I agree, that I didn't provided my question with any screenshots or examples first and just gave a summary of my search for a right function. But after I posted the examples, one of the commentators agreed, that some systems can store creation date:

[image]

So what I want to ask here: does my question really look like a garbage and I should be more precisely with the examples, tags and/or title of the question or were those who downvoted my question just too fast?

I really want to understand this issue and I as said in the comments to my much downvoted question:

> I would rather be an idiot for 5 minutes than not to ask the question
>   which is bothering me.

Thank you!

**EDIT:** 
I deleted my question, because I didn't specify it correctly, chose false tags - and that's why it already got eight downvotes. And I think that many of them who could potentially give me an answer already saw my bad formulated question. I will do some research on the topic and then I will consider if I should post this question later again. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: It's not a super bad question, but there's room for improvement. Try editing the question to show how to reproduce it. For example: **(1)** Create a new Word file and save it **(2)** Wait a few minutes **(3)** Copy the file to a different location **(4)** Execute `some code`, the result is `X` while I want `Y` as seen in this screenshot

Comment: Especially since your screenshots are in german you should also show what you expect and what the actual output is, so people don't have to learn german to know what values you want to get.

Comment: Do you think I could try to repost my question with editions - or would it be too violating the rules of SO?

Comment: Well, there are several comments under your question, which shows that the question is quite unclear to them. So ...?

Comment: Well, that was a bit unnecessary.  But you would have to be lucky enough to find somebody that understands what "real" means.  Which is the creation date as recorded in the Word document itself, not the date that is recorded in the file system.  Pretty unlikely to find somebody like that in [python] or [r] tags.

Comment: Well...this is SO life, friend ..irrespective of how many people may find your question coherent, if some find it not enough so, you end up getting whipped. You have to live with it :) I loved your statement  "I would rather be an idiot for 5 minutes than not to ask the question which is bothering me." I am sure almost everybody would have passed through this stage. It is like ragging in college :-D

Comment: @tom why don't they ask to make it more clear? why to vote down? and not directly, some users don't know english like the native people, for me, I am not an english native guy, I find it very hard to explain what I want and what I mean..

Comment: @HadiHassan They did and of course they can downvote. That's the point of downvoting, they felt it isn't a good question *now*. They may revert that after the question has been updated. If you have a problem to explain your issue/question, then ask someone to help you here. A question isn't helpful if other people don't know what you're asking about. It doesn't need to be perfect english, but it should be understandable.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This got mentioned in the comments, but for completeness it should be in an answer as well: **you never actually mentioned the source of the creation time you were looking to retrieve**.

You're looking to retrieve metadata from a Word document. There are several ways to do that (and multiple relevant questions on SO already, though the answers are somewhat vague unless you already know what you're doing, so a more focused one wouldn't hurt), but the crucial aspect of this question is that this is something that's only possible for *certain types of files*. One might be able to gain an understanding of this by a careful reading of your question, but for a reader unfamiliar with the capabilities of Office document metadata or COM structured storage, this question makes no sense - it would appear as though you are asking the impossible.

Next time, lead with a brief introduction to the space in which your problem lives, *then* introduce your problem. This could be as simple as,

> I've observed that MS-Word documents (and some similar formats) contain within them a creation date that is independent of the filesystem timestamp. There would appear to be a standard way to retrieve this information, as the system displays it in the standard properties dialog - so how can I retrieve this using Python?

The difference is communication. You don't just have a question, a problem that needs a solution... You have a story: a setting, characters, and a plot. Make sure you're telling your story, not just asking your question...

Comment: It is obvious the OP meant metadata, especially that they clarified they do *not* mean file system time. The downvoters that don't realize this probably wouldn't contribute much anyway. It's annoying how one needs to explain themselves to people that aren't even relevant.

Comment: @rr That's also very much a question of which tags you are posting in.  A Windows question in a Windows topic is fine, but a Windows topic in [tag:python] [tag:r] needs to explain to those who are not familiar with the platform that this is a thing.

Comment: From the point of view of the filesystem (or a person who knows more about filesystems than they know about word processors), the filesystem's modification timestamp *is* part of "the metadata of the file". That other stuff is inside the file, and therefore not metadata.

Comment: Yeah... Which is why explicitly noting the type of file is so critical here, @Wumpus - even filesystem metadata varies between filesystem, so one could imagine a similar question that *was* only focused on filesystem metadata.

Comment: "*Make sure you're telling your story, not just asking your question...*" that should be the next SO swag t-shirt

Comment: "You know my question, not my story." - Shog

Comment: So what you're saying is that it is okay to downvote a question you don't understand because you are not familiar enough with the topic ? If someone thinks the OP is asking for the impossible, why not just answer "it's impossible" instead of downvoting ?

Comment: @rr Well `File Properties -> Details` sounded well the same as `Right Click on File -> Properties -> Details`. I stand the Q was badly written, specially without any precision on the file type. I asked myself if the OP was talking about this kind of metadata, but as OP had not cleared it up when a comment asked him why the path creation time is not the file time I wasn't really sure, and I hate answering on a guess. So it's not that I don't know the inner of NTFS clusters (inode) or Word file format, it's just that the Q was bad at the time I saw it.

Comment: @undu If the question is missing essential information (like, in this case, that it's about a Microsoft Word document), then yes, downvoting is completely warranted (as is voting to close as unclear), because being "familiar enough" in such cases would basically require telepathy. It's a bit like asking "What's the fastest way to get to Chicago?" on Travel.SE, but forgetting to specify where you're starting from or what modes of transport you have available. Sure, if I knew the asker personally, I might be able to guess the missing context and answer them, but that's not usually the case.

Comment: [...] In this case, the question *did* happen to contain a clue about the file type, but only in the screenshot. I don't think we can blame voters for missing that. (As it happens, the text in the screenshot was in German, with bits of some Slavic language that I don't recognize off the top of my head. That surely didn't encourage most people on this English language site to examine it in any detail.) Of course, we can't really blame the OP for not realizing in advance that the type of the file was relevant either; but that doesn't make their question any clearer or more answerable.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yep, my bad, I reacted a bit strongly to this answer without giving OP's question that much thought. I now see why people downvoted it.

Answer (score 26):

I wouldn't focus on the votes. I've been using Stack Overflow for years and I've yet to find much rhyme or reason to why people choose to upvote/downvote. I've seen absolutely *horrid* questions actually garner upvotes, while questions that are really not that bad get downvoted into oblivion. Just last week I got a downvote on an answer with 250 upvotes. What was that for? Who knows.

Instead, simply try to craft the best question you can. Pay attention to the comments, as if there are problems, people will often tell you what you need to fix (post more code, give more detail, etc.), and be responsive with that. Make the requested changes in a *timely* manner. Not only will that give you a better chance of getting an answer before your question gets lost in the deluge of new questions, but it shows you're putting in effort. Too many people post drive-by questions and never respond to requests for additional information. Being responsive shows that as a potential answerer, I'm not just wasting my time with you.

Also, remember that all things are reversible. If you post a question that garners a bunch of downvotes but improve and expand upon it, some will reverse their downvotes, while others may even upvote you. Over time, a good question that started off bad can reverse its standing.

Lastly, I know rep seems really important when you don't have much, but it's really not. The most important thing is being part of a community, helping others and getting help when you need it. Focus on that, and the rest pretty much comes naturally.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I very appreciate when users with much experience share it with less experienced users. And what you said, sounds inspiring.

Comment: A trap I have fallen into lies with the _premise_ of the question. "A and B do not work because of C. Why?" The premise of C has to be made of something more robust than straw or those big bad downvoters will blow your question away. (I like straw actually) :)

Comment: "It's not about the nail."